# Postgres docker does not create user defined in .env file

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run my app and a postgresql server via docker. I created a `docker-compose.yml` file that seems to be correct from what I have researched, but postgres is only creating the default `postgres` user.

I will try to include all relevant files and cli outputs.

`docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  db-data:
```

`.env`

```
POSTGRES_USER="user123"
POSTGRES_PASSWORD="password456"
POSTGRES_DB="db"
POSTGRES_PORT="5432"
POSTGRES_HOST="localhost"
POSTGRES_URL="postgresql://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@${POSTGRES_HOST}:${POSTGRES_PORT}/${POSTGRES_DB}?schema=public"
```

`PS > psql -h localhost -U user123`

```
psql: error: FATAL:  role "user123" does not exist
```

`PS > docker exec api_db_1 env`

```
HOSTNAME=31876238fb66
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_HOST=localhost
POSTGRES_URL=postgresql://user123:password456@localhost:5432/db?schema=public
POSTGRES_USER=user123
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password456
POSTGRES_DB=db
GOSU_VERSION=1.16
LANG=en_US.utf8
PG_MAJOR=15
PG_VERSION=15.2-1.pgdg110+1
PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data
HOME=/root
```

`postgres=# SELECT usename from pg_user;`

```
 usename
----------
 postgres
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1):

The user is only created when Postgres initializes an empty database. If you have an existing database in your volume, the POSTGRES_USER variable isn't used.

From the [docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres):

> Warning: the Docker specific variables will only have an effect if you
> start the container with a data directory that is empty; any
> pre-existing database will be left untouched on container startup.

Comment: I removed the volume multiple times if that is what you are referring to

Comment: @oskar did you ever end up getting this resolved?